# Processwire Admin 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, windows-server, processwire

I have a problem here. I have built a site with Processwire on localhost and then transferred to my customer's server. a) it's a windows server (unfortunately) and b) there is a domain-mapping for this site, the domain points to a folder of another domain. Sorry, I can't explain it any better, I don't really understand the different types of servers (why do they have to be different anyway...).

My problem is, that I see the main website but not the admin page. Do I have to add anything to my .htaccess file?

I also tried to include web.config file. Not .htaccess nor web.config file have an impact when changing its content. I really have no clue what to do!!

Links: mcconnellacademy.ch, mcconnellacademy.ch/admin

Thanks for any pointing in the right direction!

Comment: Could you post the contents of web.config ?

Comment: here's the file: http://rolspace.net/web.config

Comment: Put `echo $config->urls->admin` in a template file - that will give the url to your admin - it _might_ not be what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks, DaveP for the tip. Unfortunately, again, I guess because it is a windows-server, it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you install clean Processwire on your server, can you access admin page?

If yes, its better for compatibility to create site profile from your localhost site, and on remote server install new site with this site profile.

`https://modules.processwire.com/modules/process-export-profile/`

I am always moving sites from localhost to live server this way.

Comment: Hi Pavel, I just did a fresh installation of Processwire. The admin-page is not reachable (error 404). Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm, sorry, no ideas here. I have no experience with windows server.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possibly a RewriteBase issue?
https://processwire.com/docs/tutorials/troubleshooting-guide/page3